# Conversão Doc to PDF com Syncfusion dll altera cor de tipo de letra

Tags: pdf, conversão

Estou a fazer uma conversão de um documento DOC para PDF, em VB.Net utilizando a dll Syncfusion e está a alterar a cor do meu cabeçalho. Tenho no Word de Template Fundo azul e letra Branca, e está a ficar com letra Preta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtive a solução numa resposta à mesma questão no Stack overflow inglês.
O problema era mesmo a configuração do documento word, pois os cabeçalhos estavam definidos com cor da letra Automatic, por defeito, e ao converter ficavam em preto, enquanto que ao abrir no Word, fazia o render e, como era um Heading, colocava a letra a branco no fundo escuro.
Assim, bastou colocar no word a cor da letra dos cabeçalhos como Branco, em vez de Auto e a conversão já está a funcionar.